# Testing Snort Rules

Tags: scapy, snort, intrusion-detection

I am using the pulledpork to get my rules daily. I want to be able to test these rules and make sure everything is working. Is there anything out there that is up to date and working? I know rules2alert is there but it is vastly unfinished and hasn't been touched in a while. When I run it on my pulledpork rules I get many errors.

Comment: Do you have some specific rules in mind you want to check? (i.e. specific signatures) Or you want to check the coverage of the ruleset?

Comment: @EriksDobelis well i'd prefer to test the level 1 priority alerts. But the idea would be to be able to test all rules.

Comment: rules2alert seems to be the closest response. I am not aware of anything better suited. You just need to fix the bugs :)

Comment: @EriksDobelis I am trying. I also have no background with scapy or packet manipulation, so it's going quite slow. ~_~

Comment: If you use python3 version and have some particular issue, feel free to post it to http://github.com/phaethon/scapy

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to attempt to use a script with Scapy to automatically generate traffic that will trip rules. However, there exists a service with which you can generate a number of IDS alerts using just a command line tools such as `wget` and `curl` or your browser - [testmyids.com (blog post)](http://blog.testmyids.com/2015/01/8-years-of-testmyids.html).

Just run `wget testmyids.com` to trip the "GPL ATTACK_RESPONSE id check returned root" signature. This is the most basic check. Website contains details about more complex checks for file-format or executables detailed in the link.